# Is the select with named parameter query correct?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, eclipse

Is the below query correct ?

```
final String sqlQuery = "select  e.COMM,  e.DEPTNO,  e.EMPNO,  e.ENAME from EMP e where
 DATE between(:joinDate and :relievDate  )";
 Map namedParameters = new HashMap();
 namedParameters.put("joinDate", new Date(2000-01-02));
 namedParameters.put("relievDate", new Date(2010-03-04));
 List result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlQuery, namedParameters);
```

Comment: Missing double quote at the end of the SQL maybe

Comment: then ,What is correct query?

Comment: new Date(2000-01-02) looks very dubious to me. BTW, the easiest way to find out if something is right is to throw the code in, run it, and see if it works. Best way to learn.

Comment: sqlQuery is correct or not?

Comment: just try it - and you will know if it is correct!

Comment: And take the brackets off from around (:joinDate and :relievDate  )

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
namedParameters.put("joinDate", new Date(df.parse("2000-01-02")));
namedParameters.put("relievDate", new Date(df.parse("2000-03-04")));
```

Try this to get a better date format that can be used in the query.